# Git not running on windows 7

Tags: git, chef-infra, knife

I have installed git and chef-workstation on Windows 7. Whenever I try to run "chef" or "knife" command it gives error. It shows that "bash: chef: command not found". Please help me with this

Comment: you must setup environment variables to absolute path to your executables :) or run them from where you installed them

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chef/chef-dk#powershell shows how to configure PowerShell to find the ChefDK commands.